# Hazelcast distributed map processor execution on a single node

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cluster-computing, hazelcast

I use Hazelcast within Spring Boot MVC application that supports high availability, it has 4 instances of the same logic which run as active-active.
All of the 4 share one distributed map of objects.

As a result of user action (access to specific controller) I trigger a EntryProcessor (map.submitToKey) on the shared map. I thought that such action would run the processor only once, on a single node, but instead all of the 4 nodes run the same processor at the same time.

Is there an option to execute distributed map's EntryProcessor on a single node?

Comment: When submitted via `map.submitToKey(...)`, `EntryProcessor` is executed once for the specific key on a single node. Additionally, `EntryBackupProcessor`s returned by `EntryProcessor.getBackupProcessor()` are executed on backup nodes, if the map has backup configured (there is single backup by default). How do you detect it's executed on all 4 nodes?

Comment: @mdogan I've detected it via logging, though I checked it and you're right. The processors are executed on primary + backup nodes.
Is it dangerous to have a processor without a backup processor? I guess that this is what my business logic demands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your map doesn't need any backups then `EntryProcessor` can safely return `null` from [getBackupProcessor()](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.5/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/EntryProcessor.html#getBackupProcessor--). When returned `null`, backup nodes will not execute any `EntryBackupProcessor`.

Otherwise if you configured backups for map but return `null` for [EntryBackupProcessor](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.5/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/EntryBackupProcessor.html), then entry won't be replicated to the backup nodes. It will treated as if there's no backups configured for map. Primary and backups will become inconsistent eventually. When primary crashes you will lose the updates done by `EntryProcessor`.

In this case, if you need backups, you can write a custom `EntryBackupProcessor`, which can just replicate the result of primary `EntryProcessor`'s execution, instead of executing `EntryProcessor`'s logic. For example:

```
class CustomEntryBackupProcessor implements EntryBackupProcessor {

    private Object resultOfEntryProcessor;

    @Override
    public void processBackup(Map.Entry entry) {
        entry.setValue(resultOfEntryProcessor);            
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, this example could be a good idea, I will give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, if I set the BackupProcessor to null, and use entry.setValue(newValue) in the end of the EntryProcessor, would the entry syncronize to the backup? If so, I guess there is no need in a CustomBackupProcessor, right?

Comment: If `EntryBackupProcessor ` is null, then entry will not sync to the backup nodes. It will treated as if there's no backups configured for map. So, when primary crashes you will lose the updates done by `EntryProcessor `. It's better to write a custom backup processor... PS: I've updated the answer.